# the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `actix_web::Scope`

Tags: rust, routes, actix-web

I want to group my app routes in scope, so I can separate their file location per Domain in the future.
what I'm trying to do is convert

```rust
HttpServer::new(move || App::new().app_data(app_state.clone()).service(delete_comment).service(update_comment).service(get_comments).service(create_comment))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
        .run()
        .await
```

to:

```rust
let comment_scope =  web::scope("/comments").service(delete_comment).service(update_comment).service(get_comments).service(create_comment);
HttpServer::new(move || App::new().app_data(app_state.clone()).service(comment_scope))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
        .run()
        .await
```

but it keeps telling me that the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `actix_web::Scope`.
how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to move the `comment_scope` declaration into `new` closure:

```rust
HttpServer::new(move || {
      
        let comment_scope = web::scope("/comments")
        .service(delete_comment)
        .service(update_comment)
        .service(get_comments)
        .service(create_comment);

        App::new()
            .service(comment_scope)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
```

Answer (score 0):

How about try this by using TcpListener:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;
pub fn run(listener: TcpListener) -> Result<Server, std::io::Error> {
    let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .route("/comments", web::post().to(comments))
            [/.../]
    })
        .listen(listener)?
        .run();
    Ok(server)
}
```

Comment: What does replacing `.bind` with `.listen` have to do with configuring the routes?